# Why did I fail this first post audit?

Tags: support, review-queues, disputed-review-audits, new-users, first-post-review

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/10800009

Just in case you can't see the answer in question there, it's:

> You just need to wrap img and figcaption inside figure tag :)

It turns out that this was actually the correct answer, as the accepted answer says the exact same thing:

> Basically you need to change in your html. You should take image and figcaption in figure tag.

So why did so many people recommend deletion?

Comment: probably because many equate short answer with bad answer.

Comment: At a minimum, the answer needed some editing, and was poorly explained, so a downvote and/or comment would also be meritted.  Saying that it "looks good" from the FP queue is very clearly wrong.  That said, I don't see it as meriting deletion.

Comment: IMHO that was a bad audit.  It was an answer and should not have been deleted.

Comment: @NathanOliver It shouldn't have been deleted, but it *does* need moderation action, so it's not really such a problem as an audit.  You'll pass the audit if you indicate that it needs moderation action (which it does) and you'll fail if you say it's fine as is, which its really not.

Comment: @Servy how can I tell whether or not an answer is poorly explained?

Comment: @Houseman By reading it.

Comment: @Servy I read it, and it looked like a fine explanation to me, along with others who both agree and disagree so it seems like there's more to it than that.

Comment: To me, comparing the deleted answer with the accepted makes it quite clear why one was removed. Notice the accepted answer has much more information (more than what you've pasted here).

Comment: @CubeJockey So quantity, not quality?

Comment: It's not a super obvious audit, but the audit is correct.  That new answer was poorly formatted and could have used some editing.  For example removing the needless noise (the `:)`) making the keywords readable.

Comment: @Houseman are you implying the accepted answer isn't of higher quality...? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34409551/4771017) is a direct link.

Comment: @CubeJockey I'm not implying anything. You only mentioned "more information", so was just asking to confirm that "more information" was all there was to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that you are on the first post queue where you are supposed to look for pearls that need to be salvaged.

The question is showing html markup with a jsfiddle included and asks why the layout isn't as expected.

Good answers would have shown the actual markup, code or CSS needed that shows how to fix the issue. Great answers would have expanded to link to documentation for the used tags and explained which mistake the OP made.

The answer that was used here as an audit is a low effort attempt to answer but if that is all the time I want to spend on an answer I leave a comment instead. The hints of value might be slightly helpful for future visitors that know what they are doing but it isn't the type of answers we would like to see on Stack Overflow.

Leaving a comment to suggest improvement and/or a down vote are the correct actions here. Looks OK certainly isn't.

In that sense the audit is great and by failing it you got the opportunity to improve your knowledge about how to review in the first-post queue.